# Why doesn't transform work in my code on hover?

Tags: html, css

I have a division with hole in between, when I rotate it on direct hover it works; but when I try to rotate it while hovering on another division `#btn` it doesn't work. I don't understand why?

I've made the hole using the `:after` element;

Here's my code:

```css
/* This Part doesn't work (#btn:hover>.hollowBox) */
#btn:hover>.hollowBox {
  transform: perspective(800px) rotateY(25deg);
}

/* Following part works comment out the upper part and uncomment the code below */
/*.hollowBox:hover{
  transform: perspective(800px) rotateY(25deg);
}*/

.hollowBox {
  background: #ddd;
  position: relative;
  width: 60%;
  height: 40%;
}

.hollowBox:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background: #222;
  width: 80%;
  height: 80%;
  top: 10%;
  left: 10%;
}

#btn {
  background: wheat;
  padding: 0.3em
}

body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background: #222;
}
```

```html
<div class='hollowBox'></div><br><br>
<div id='btn'>Hover Me</div>
```

Comment: `>` is the [child combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_combinator) and hollowbox isn't a child of btn

Comment: I had tried the same code with (#btn:hover + .hollowBox), (#btn:hover ~ .hollowBox) (#btn:hover .hollowBox) & (#btn:hover > .hollowBox), just like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4502633/how-to-affect-other-elements-when-a-div-is-hovered suggests but nothing worked.

Comment: Of course this doesn’t work either, the elements are in the wrong order for that. You can only select downwards or to the right in the DOM with CSS, not upwards or to the left.

Comment: you should understand the meaning of each selector and not only apply them.